# Future Progressive tense

Tags: tenses, future

I'm quite good at English,but not adept in it. Over a period of time I've gotten a good grip over it and I could ponder a lot about grammar in detail. I've doubt regarding the following Qs. and need details and if it is right why and how convict me with grammar.

> 1. *You'll get a chance to see macy play live.* (I think Correct)
>      or
>      *You'll get a chance to see macy playing live.* (Not Correct)
> 2. *How to stop your hair become white?* (I think Correct)
>      or
>      *How to stop your hair becoming white?* (Not Correct)

Comment: _a good grip on it_ is the idiom. I don't understand "to the granularity", unless you mean "at a closer level"; that's not an idiom in American English. Also, put spaces between sentences. Periods are too small and this is not Thai. This is not "Future Progressive Tense", btw; there is no such thing in English. You appear to be asking about aspectual verbs like _stop_ and sense verbs like _see_, both of which have extremely specialized and irregular syntax; nothing can be concluded without more context and examples.

Comment: If you are learning English this site http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions is specifically designed for English Language Learners.

Comment: No. Labels should be correct / correct / incorrect / correct. See the [to see them play and to see them playing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148694/to-see-them-play-and-to-see-them-playing) thread (where there is just 'the right answer' without underpinning logic). (John Lawler can give the underpinning  logic.) There are the usual few internet misusages of 'to stop it become' where '... becoming' should be used.

Comment: Whoever said those "incorrect" sentences are wrong was misinformed. There is nothing wrong with either 1a or 1b, and 2a is definitely wrong.

Comment: Infinitive verb is used when action is still going on and -ing is i.e. verb+ing  used when the action is still in progress.Thanks all

Comment: @mahesh. I'm curious to know what's the difference between 'still going on' and 'still in progress.'

Comment: Both conveys the  same idea.